# Is setting CentOS user home-dir as NGINX server block root secure for vsftpd?

Tags: centos, security, vsftpd, nginx

This is what I did:

1. CentOS 6.2 server
2. installed nginx
3. installed vsftpd
4. in vsftpd.conf I set `chroot_local_user=YES`
5. created a new user "bleh"
6. created directory `/home/bleh/public_html/`
7. in virtual.conf I set location / { root to `/home/bleh/public_html/`
8. and finally did `chmod 755 /home/bleh/`

Is this safe? Is this acceptable?

I ran into all sorts of permission problems when I tried to use `/var/www/` as
root. The above worked and the server is delivery data.

Answer (score 0):

That may be bad security for a few reasons.

1. If `/var` or `/var/www` is on its own partition, it may have been mounted with special restrictions. For example, it may have been mounted with options such as `noexec` or `nosuid`. `/home` might not have these restrictions.
2. In many cases, the directory from which you are hosting your website should not be world-readable. You should generally make your content only readable by its owner and group. Your webserver should be run as a user that can read those files.
3. Mixing server data in with user data might lead to the accidental hosting of sensitive data. For example, you might accidentally host the user `blah`'s data.